# web2py and column aliasing

Tags: sql, web2py

I have a query in the controller like this (many columns are commented out)

```
rows=db( (c.email_sent == 0 ) & (c.status=='pending') ).select(db.f.first_name #.with_alias('requester_name') ,
# db.t.first_name.with_alias('receiver_name'),db.t.email.with_alias('sendto_email'),
# db.c.from_id.with_alias('sender_id'),db.c.to_id.with_alias('receiver_id'),
# db.c.id.with_alias('connection_id')
,join = 
[db.f.on (db.f.id==c.from_id),
db.t.on(db.t.id==c.to_id)]
    )
```

The view has

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<table class="table">
    {{for row in rows:}}
    <tr>
        <td>={{row.first_name}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and it works fine. But if I remove the commented out aliasing from the controller, I can't get the view to work. I get an error - "(something wrong in Rows object)"
The function argument list is (self=, sqlrows=, linkto=None, upload=None, orderby=None, headers={}, truncate=16, columns=['f.first_name AS requester_name', 't.first_name AS receiver_name', 't.email AS sendto_email', 'c.from_id AS sender_id', 'c.to_id AS receiver_id', 'c.id AS connection_id'], th_link='', extracolumns=None, selectid=None, renderstyle=False, cid=None, colgroup=False, **attributes={})
Obviously the column names are not getting passed correctly. How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you alias a field, then use the alias when accessing that field in the row:

```
{{=row.requester_name}}
```

Another option is to skip using the aliases -- they don't appear to be necessary. In that case, because the query involves a join, you would access individual field values via `row.tablename.fieldname`.

Comment: row.tablename.fieldname did not help (when using aliases). Thisis what printing rows displayed -<Row {'requester_name': u'Jayadevan', '_extra': {'f.first_name AS requester_name': 'Jayadevan'}}>

Comment: OK, my return syntax in the controller was wrong (am a newbie). It had to be  return dict(rows=rows). I was doing return rows

Comment: Note, I suggested using `row.tablename.fieldname` syntax assuming you do *not* use aliases.